# Is there a reason Selenium could be causing content-length to expand in size?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So I'm using Selenium + ChromeDriver (v93) to do some automations on a form.  Usually I have no issue.  The form when submitted successfully produces a modal and an XHR on the network side that confirms the deal went through.

Today, I tried my script and dealt with hang time.  The XHR was pending, so I tried submitting the form manually without and sure enough it worked just fine.  So I check the content-lengths of the XHR requests and I saw it at 233 - reminder this was when I did it manually.

SO - I check the content-lengths of the XHR when using Selenium, same settings, same inputs and the content-lengths boomed in size to 8284883.  So I'm like, okay maybe its a size issue and extend my wait time for it to go through.  What normally takes ms to finish took a minute.

I'm not too concerned but I'm stuck on what exactly ChromeDriver or Selenium could be doing to increase content-lengths, its just sending an image (in binary), and a few text fields.

I'm just trying to figure out if this is common, or what the story might be.  Thanks!

Comment: Add more details. Like screenshots of both requests.

Comment: You're saying that when you do it manually the content-length is `233` bytes. Do you think your image with text takes `233` bytes?

Comment: @AlexeyR it states that the image is (binary).  So possible?  Is there a way to deconstruct the XHR and see what exactly what is making the request that big in content?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.